# Xpath vs. CSS selector in Scrapy: Why is data stored differently?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I can use two different methods to extract the title of an article: xpath vs. css. They will give me the same results, but there is one difference. Using xpath will store the data (json file) in square brackets `["Some Title"]`, while the css selector will simply store data without brackets `"Some Title"`. I actually don't want to store the data with brackets. **How do I do this with using xpath?**

Here is my code for extracting the title of a document:

**CSS Selector**

```
def parse_article(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).get(default='').strip() 


    yield {
        'title': extract_with_css('div#title h2::text')           
          }
```

**Xpath**

```
 def parse_article(self, response):
    def extract_with_xpath(query):
        return response.xpath(query).extract() 


    yield {
        'title': extract_with_xpath('//div[@id="title"]/h2/text()') 
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your code from `extract()` to `get()`:

```
def extract_with_xpath(query):
    return response.xpath(query).get(default='').strip()
```

Method `extract` return all the matches, and `get` only first one.

Comment: Is it actually possible to use both methods according to the data I want to extract? Let's say for the "title" I only want to have the first match (like you described), but for e.g. "keywords" (which are stored in a meta tag in head) I want all matches. Of course your method works, but there is actually just one title, but more keywords. Now, I only get the first keyword.

Comment: Create another syntax sugar for extract and use in needed places. For example, use `extract_with_xpath` with `extract` and create `get_with_xpath `  for `get`. In `extract` you can use something like `' '.join([i.strip() for i in response.xpath(query).extract()])`.

Comment: Or just use clear syntax without any extra functions.

Comment: Right! I start to understand better. Thank you.